# OpenGl texture wrapping

Tags: opengl

How does OpenGL calculate the new texture coordinate when wrapping with `GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT`? I mean given (x, y) what formula is applied? https://open.gl/textures

Comment: What _formula_? Something like this I guess `if(int(x) is odd) x = frac(x) else x = 1 - frac(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 8.14.2 Coordinate Wrapping and Texel Selection; page 257, Table 8.20](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

> ```
> MIRRORED_REPEAT : (size − 1) − mirror(coord mod (2 × size)) − size)
> ```
>
> where `mirror(a)` returns a `if a ≥ 0`, and `−(1 + a)` otherwise.

This means if the texture is tiled then the even tiles are draw as the texture is and the odd tiles are drawn mirrored.

If the texture coordinate are in [0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], ..., then the *wrap* function returns a corresponding coordinate in range [0, 1].
If the texture coordinate are in [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], ...,  then the *wrap* function returns a corresponding mirrored coordinate in range [1, 0].

The *wrap* function is applied to each coordinate separately and for each coordinate a separate, different *wrap* function can be set.

Comment: Is there a missing parenthesis in the specification? The last one has no opening

Comment: @Yamahari Yes you are right, in the specification is missing a parenthesis. The opening parenthesis should be at the begin of the expression. I'll try to find a correct specification.